# how to use two table data with select

Tags: sql

Hi can anybody help me to write a query for my purpose to join data between two table..

Here is detail..

I have taken two table

Table1= usertb

```
id   name  age city 

1    David  29  Japan

2    John   23  UK

3    Anthony 20  Russia
```

Table2= msgtb

```
id msg senderid

1  Hi   2

1  bye  3
```

now i want to make like a page which look like inbox.. where output should be like
suppose id=1 is logged..so his inbox should be like

i dont want to print senderid..i want to print its detail

```
Message  senderName  SenderCity

Hi        JOhn         Uk

bye        Anthony     Russia...
```

Hope all can understand what i want to explain...

Please Help..Thanks..

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [show combined data of various tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144335/show-combined-data-of-various-tables) - there is no need to duplicate your own questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is about as simple as SQL gets.  I'd suggest reading online or a book about SQL -- maybe the first 3 chapters or so.

```
select m.msg, u.name, u.city
from msgtb m
join usertb u on m.senderid = u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select msgtb.msg, usertb.name, usertb.city
from msgtb,usertb where msgtb.senderid = usertb.id and msgtb.id=1
```

Comment: sorry it was my mistake...Its working...thanks a lot...i just added